# Separating float digits into an array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have a decimal (5,2) that I am trying to separate into an array.

So if the number is..

`123.45 = array([0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )`

`23.45 = array([0] => 0 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )`

`3.45 = array([0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )`

I have a pretty large code to do this, and I wanted to know if anyone had a simpler way of putting each digit into this array because I feel like mine is pretty convoluted.

```
$number = 123.35;
$number_array = explode(".", $number);
$final_array = array(0);

if(!empty(@(string)$number_array[0][0]) && !empty(@(string)$number_array[0][1]) && !empty(@(string)$number_array[0][2]))
{
    $final_array[0] = @(string)$number_array[0][0];
    $final_array[1] = @(string)$number_array[0][1];
    $final_array[2] = @(string)$number_array[0][2];
}
elseif(!empty(@(string)$number_array[0][0]) && !empty(@(string)$number_array[0][1]) && empty(@(string)$number_array[0][2]))
{
    $final_array[0] = 0;
    $final_array[1] = @(string)$number_array[0][0];
    $final_array[2] = @(string)$number_array[0][1];
}
elseif(!empty(@(string)$number_array[0][0]) && empty(@(string)$number_array[0][1]) && empty(@(string)$number_array[0][2]))
{
    $final_array[0] = 0;
    $final_array[1] = 0;
    $final_array[2] = @(string)$number_array[0][0];
}
else
{
    $final_array[0] = 0;
    $final_array[1] = 0;
    $final_array[2] = 0;
}

empty(@(string)$number_array[1][0]) ? $final_array[3] = 0 : $final_array[3] = @(string)$number_array[1][0];
empty(@(string)$number_array[1][1]) ? $final_array[4] = 0 : $final_array[4] = @(string)$number_array[1][1];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$number = str_replace('.', '', (string) 13.35);
$number = str_pad($number, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
var_dump(str_split($number));
```

Comment: This is great, but the "0"s and the size of my `final_array` are needed. I need an array(5)

Comment: Use str_pad($number, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) before the str_split

Comment: Updated - the casting to a string may not be needed, but I think it's nice to have it for clarity.

Comment: Oh, and in the future don't use the @ error suppressor!

Comment: This is awesome @Jessica! Thank you so much. The only confusing part about my problem is. The 0's need to be there on the number side. But it's actually the opposite for the decimal placements. If it's .3 I need [3]=3, [4] = 0. I guess I could do this twice, and pad_right

Comment: You might look at using number_format() instead then

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
list($whole, $decimal) = sscanf($number, '%d.%d');
$result = str_split(sprintf('%03s',$whole) . $decimal);
```

Test cases:

```
foreach ([123.45, 23.45, 3.45] as $number) {
    list($whole, $decimal) = sscanf($number, '%d.%d');
    $result = str_split(sprintf('%03s',$whole).$decimal);
    echo implode(', ', $result) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
0, 2, 3, 4, 5
0, 0, 3, 4, 5
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/144675)

Answer (score 0):

You want to take a look at phps [str_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)() function.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using regular expressions? That would be the best in your case..

Comment: The only thing i've tried it what I know how to do. If you had an example, I'd love to see it